# Android: Error while generating the main dex list

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-multidex

I got this error after adding another package for paypal ,but i have removed this error and i am still receiving the same error ,I have checked several solutions for this issue and it hasn't been solved yet.
the gradle code has been attached below.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mainproject.mainroject.story"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions
            {
                cruncherEnabled = false
            }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.2.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.5'
    implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.16.0'
    implementation 'com.craftman.cardform:cardform:0.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: try after adding this line in your dependencies: **'implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'**

Comment: it didn't work....

Comment: did you try invalidate caches and restart?

Answer (score 8):

I solved this, by increasing minsdkversion to 21. Hope this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

The file you specify in multiDexKeepFile should contain one class per line, in the format com/example/MyClass.class. For example, you can create a file called multidex-config.txt that looks like this:

```
com/example/MyClass.class
com/example/MyOtherClass.class
```

Then you can declare that file for a build type as follows:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: to make sure that i made it as u discussed. i create the file in project ..empty? ,,,,,then write the code in build gradle (app) if that write.... it didn't work with me